# Errors when trying to run a new created simple Apache Cordova Jascript project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

In Visual Studio 2017, I just created a new Javascript Apache Cordova project,  everything is by default, build it, everything is fine. When I try to run it, errors:

[image]

Also, Visual Studio will hang for about 5 minutes.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Try using node.js version 4.x which is the only version I found to work with Cordova out of the box.